# Drop element of nested list based on position

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a nested list, with each list differing in length and made up of strings:

```
list = {{"00:00 12:00 12.00 2", "12:00 17:30 5.50 2", 
    "17:30 22:00 4.50 2", 
    "22:00 24:00 2.00 2"}, {"00:00 12:00 12.00 2", 
    "12:00 17:00 5.00 2", "17:00 20:45 3.75 5", "20:45 21:00 0.25 6", 
    "21:00 21:30 0.50 6", 
    "21:30 24:00 2.50 6"}, {"00:00 02:15 2.25 6", 
    "02:15 03:00 0.75 21", "03:00 09:00 6.00 12", 
    "09:00 09:15 0.25 12", "09:15 09:45 0.50 12", 
    "09:45 10:15 0.50 12", "10:15 10:45 0.50 12", 
    "10:45 12:00 1.25 12", "12:00 15:00 3.00 12"}};
```

Id like to drop a single element of this nested list based on position. For example if I enter:

```
list[[2]][[2]]
```

it will return

```
{"12:00 17:00 5.00 2"}
```

I would like to be able to Drop or Delete this element based on this position and not any other criteria. This would return:

```
listNew = {{"00:00 12:00 12.00 2", "12:00 17:30 5.50 2", 
    "17:30 22:00 4.50 2", 
    "22:00 24:00 2.00 2"}, {"00:00 12:00 12.00 2", 
    "17:00 20:45 3.75 5", "20:45 21:00 0.25 6", "21:00 21:30 0.50 6", 
    "21:30 24:00 2.50 6"}, {"00:00 02:15 2.25 6", 
    "02:15 03:00 0.75 21", "03:00 09:00 6.00 12", 
    "09:00 09:15 0.25 12", "09:15 09:45 0.50 12", 
    "09:45 10:15 0.50 12", "10:15 10:45 0.50 12", 
    "10:45 12:00 1.25 12", "12:00 15:00 3.00 12"}};
```

I tried using:

```
Drop[list,{2},{2}]
```

but this just deleted the whole 2nd nested list. I also tried many other combinations of curly and square brackets but no luck. I know there will be a simple solution to this but I just can't find it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Delete[list, {2, 2}]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
deletepos[i_, j_] := list /. Thread[list[[i, j]] -> Nothing]
```

Then for the example in the OP

```
deletepos[2, 2]
```

and checking with the desired output

```
LinearAlgebra`Private`ZeroArrayQ[Flatten[deletepos[2, 2] - listNew]]
SameQ[Flatten[deletepos[2, 2] - listNew]]
```

both return

> [image: true]

Comment: Is there an advantage to this over simply `Delete[list, {2, 2}]` as I mentioned in a comment to the OP?

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi I never implied that there's something wrong with your comment. I just demonstrated a couple of other ways to go about obtaining the desired result. I though it to be clear that this is an additional suggestion.

Comment: I am not implying that there is something wrong with your answer either :-). Additional suggestions are great. I was wondering if there was an advantage to your suggestion over using the built-in. e.g. performs better on very long lists, handles some case that the built-in does not etc. Also is there a reason for the complicated test? Why not just `deletepos[2, 2] == listNew`.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi that's a very good point, but I did not check over a large list to be honest, though I doubt that it'd be faster than the built-in this case. Now, for the complicated test: I just thought that the author of the OP might benefit from getting exposed to an undocumented function, and hence search this site for the extra goodies :-) Then, I remembered a recent comment under an answer of mine, and I thought to demosntrate `SameQ` so the author would read some extra docs in case they were unfamiliar with said command.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is the following:

```
delpos[x_, i1_, i2_] := Module[
  {list = x, pos1 = i1, pos2 = i2},
  list[[pos1, pos2]] = Sequence[];
  list]
```

You desired output is given by

```
delpos[list, 2, 2]
```

And we can check again with `listNew`

```
LinearAlgebra`Private`ZeroArrayQ[
 Flatten@(listNew - delpos[list, 2, 2])]
SameQ[Flatten@(listNew - delpos[list, 2, 2])]
```

both return

> [image: true]